# Browser back button redirecting to home page in angular 8

Tags: angular8

Browser back button is not working. It redirects me to the home page instead of going to the previous page.
e.g
http://localhost:4200/#/component1/1
http://localhost:4200/#/component2/1
http://localhost:4200/#/component3/1

When I click back button when I am in component3 it has goes to component2 instead its going to the home page. Can anyone tell me the solution to this problem?

routing.ts

```
{
    path: 'component1/:id',
    component: Component1,
    canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard],
    data: { isId: true },
  },

  {
    path: 'component2/:id',
    component: Component2,
    canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard],
    data: { isId: true },
  },
  {
    path: 'component3/:id',
    component: Component3,
    canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard],
    data: { isId: true },
  },
```

oauthcallbackhandlerguard.service.ts

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {

    this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
    let engId: number = 0;
    let engagementDetailId: number = 0;
    if(route.data.isEngagementDetailId == true)
    {
        let engDetailData =this.engagementService.$engagementDetailId.subscribe((data) => {
            if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
                engagementDetailId = data;
       
            }
          });
    }
    else
    {
  let engData =this.engagementService.$engagementId.subscribe((data) => {
        if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
            engId = data;
   
        }
      });
    }

    let groupIds = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('groupids'));
    return this.validateUserAccess(engId, engagementDetailId, state,groupIds);

}

private validateUserAccess(engId: number, engagementDetailId: number, state: RouterStateSnapshot,groupIds:number[]): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    if (engId > 0 || engagementDetailId>0) {
        return this.authGuardService.validateUserAccess(engagementDetailId, engId,groupIds).map(response => {

            console.log(response);
             return response ? true : this.router.parseUrl('/unauthorized');
            if (response) {
                 this.router.navigate([state.url]);
            }
             else {
                 this.redictToUnAutherized();
             }
         },
          (error) => {
               console.log('auth failed. Error ', error);
                // this.redictToUnAutherized();
                 return false;
          });

    }
    else {
        return Observable.of(true);
    }
}

private redictToUnAutherized() {
    this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
}
```

Comment: Can you run your app in a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

1- Run your app in diffrent browser

2- Add default routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
 {
    path: 'component1/:id',
    component: Component1,
    canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard],
    data: { isId: true },
  },

  {
    path: 'component2/:id',
    component: Component2,
    canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard],
    data: { isId: true },
  },
  {
    path: 'component3/:id',
    component: Component3,
    canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard],
    data: { isId: true },
  },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

3- Try to check in OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard if it is going to navigate page back and allow it with Auth

```
  constructor (private _location: Location) 
   
  this._location.back();
```

Comment: Thank you. I did as you said, even though its going to home page. Instead of going to the previous page.

Comment: for testing purposes only. You may remove 
    `canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard],
    data: { isId: true },`from all routes save and run ng serve.

Comment: yes its working if I remove the canActivate: [OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard] but its necessary to include.

Comment: can you share the Guard (update the question) code ? because it is very possible that the bug is there.

Comment: Sure. I shared it.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem arises when validating the access back. To debug that try to place a `console.log("PLACE OF CONSOLE DESCRITPTION", ACTION OR STRING)` in each branch of the code, to the input and output of the method ..

Comment: OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard is called when i click on respective components when I click on browser back without hitting OAuthCallbackHandlerGuard going to home page. Whenever router navigation happens i will write to window history right but its not writing also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234114/discussion-between-hamada-and-poongodi).